# Extract URLs from text file

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file with many different URL typed in the text.

For example:

```
file:///g:/somepath/subpath/file.txt 
/somepath/subpath/file.txt 
Http://www.domain.at/path/file.txt
```

I need them to be extracted from the file. In the text file there is no HTML, so I cannot search for something like href.

Is there a RegEx for PHP that I can use?

Comment: There are several, but no human knows them by heart. Ask Google.

Comment: If each is on a separate line or has the same separator, just read the file and explode it.

Comment: the links are in the middle of the text, there is no special sign to explode them.

Answer (score 1):

Post entire file if you want more help. From given...

```
<?php

$string = 'file:///g:/somepath/subpath/file.txt 
dasdsaddasdf
                 dsafddsad           /somepath/subpath/file.txt 
    Http://www.domain.at/path/file.txt adsadsadasd
';

preg_match_all('#([\S]+)\.txt#is', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);

?>
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => file:///g:/somepath/subpath/file
    [1] => /somepath/subpath/file
    [2] => Http://www.domain.at/path/file
)
```