# Extract specific data from a text file with PHP

Tags: php

I have a text file of 3,500 urls. This text file is composed of 2,500 .com domains urls and 1,000 .es domains urls in the following format :

> http://www.domain1.com
>
> http://www.domain3.es
>
> ...

How can I scrape the full .es URLs and extract them to new text file using a PHP ?

Comment: search harder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526131/extract-urls-from-text-file

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it

```
$source = fopen("inputfile", "r");
$destination = fopen("outputfile", "w");

if ($source && $destination) {
    while (($line = fgets($source))) {
        if (strpos($line,'.es')) {

            fwrite($destination, $line); 
        }

    }
    fclose($source);
    fclose($destination);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
/*read whole file into array*/
$linkList = file("path/to/file");
/*filter array*/
$filteredList = preg_grep("/\.es$/", $linkList);
/*write it back to file*/ 
file_put_contents('newFile.txt', implode("\n", $filteredList));
```